# Error occurs on setting of zeppelin

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I installed zeppelin-0.6.2 in my computer and created new note on zeppelin WEBUI.

When I executed the print statement, I got the error like picture below.

[image]

So I checked my log file in zeppelin directory. Here is my log record.

> java.net.BindException: Address already in use Error
>
> ERROR [2016-11-25 13:56:06,336] ({pool-1-thread-5}
>   TThreadPoolServer.java[run]:296) - Error occurred during processing of
>   message.

I checked port 8082 which is not listening port.(plus, spark port is 4040)

Even I set up `zeppelin.server.port : 8082`, I don't know why this error appears.

plus, I checked spark WEBUI.

I don't know this below picture is right... why is running two zeppelin app?

[image]

Here are my zeppelin conf files.

zeppelin-env.sh

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop_eco/spark/
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_101
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop_eco/hadoop/etc/conf
export MASTER=spark://m01:7077
```

zeppelin-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>zeppelin.server.addr</name>
  <value>m01</value>
  <description>Server address</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>zeppelin.server.port</name>
  <value>8082</value>
  <description>Server port.</description>
</property>
```

And This is logs

```
 WARN [2016-12-09 02:30:42,972] ({pool-1-thread-5} AbstractLifeCycle.java[setFailed]:212) - FAILED org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server@4eb0c79f: java.net.BindException: address already in use
java.net.BindException: address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)
        at org.spark_project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.org$apache$spark$ui$JettyUtils$$connect$1(JettyUtils.scala:298)
        at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(JettyUtils.scala:308)
        at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(JettyUtils.scala:308)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:2071)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:2062)
        at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$.startJettyServer(JettyUtils.scala:308)
        at org.apache.spark.ui.WebUI.bind(WebUI.scala:139)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$10.apply(SparkContext.scala:451)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$10.apply(SparkContext.scala:451)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:451)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2256)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:831)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:823)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:823)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkSession(SparkInterpreter.java:337)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkSession(SparkInterpreter.java:217)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:816)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.getProgress(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:110)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer.getProgress(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:404)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Processor$getProgress.getResult(RemoteInterpreterService.java:1509)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Processor$getProgress.getResult(RemoteInterpreterService.java:1494)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:285)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR [2016-12-09 02:30:43,086] ({pool-1-thread-5} Utils.java[invokeMethod]:40) -
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkSession(SparkInterpreter.java:337)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkSession(SparkInterpreter.java:217)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:816)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.getProgress(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:110)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer.getProgress(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:404)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Processor$getProgress.getResult(RemoteInterpreterService.java:1509)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Processor$getProgress.getResult(RemoteInterpreterService.java:1494)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:285)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener$.initEventLog(EventLoggingListener.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.start(EventLoggingListener.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:519)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2256)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:831)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$8.apply(SparkSession.scala:823)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:823)
        ... 20 more
 INFO [2016-12-09 02:30:43,086] ({pool-1-thread-5} SparkInterpreter.java[createSparkSession]:338) - Created Spark session with Hive support
ERROR [2016-12-09 02:30:43,086] ({pool-1-thread-5} TThreadPoolServer.java[run]:296) - Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:38)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.Utils.invokeMethod(Utils.java:33)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext_2(SparkInterpreter.java:367)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.createSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:356)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.getSparkContext(SparkInterpreter.java:138)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkInterpreter.open(SparkInterpreter.java:818)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.getProgress(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:110)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer.getProgress(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:404)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Processor$getProgress.getResult(RemoteInterpreterService.java:1509)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Processor$getProgress.getResult(RemoteInterpreterService.java:1494)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:285)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

jps result

```
19568 Master
9188 SecondaryNameNode
9460 ResourceManager
8887 NameNode
25192 SparkSubmit
25709 Jps
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That means, one of port used by zeppelin is already consumed by other applications. Could it try again after reboot or / stopping other applications while rollback 8082 port to 8080.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it!
Have a nice day~

Comment: @1ambda could you answer one more question? If you don't mind.
I just did it as you said. but It was not worked. 
I tried to solve this error by searching in google. but there were little information about zeppelin's error. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Hi. Please could you explain your env? (e.g OS, Java) Also. it would be helpful to attach full error logs and `jps` result.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I edited my question just now.
I've tried to solve this problem, but It's not worked..

Comment: @1ambda The OS is CENTOS 7.0.

Comment: One more thing. Could you verify that there is no process which is using 8080 by executing CLI command in shell? (e.g `netstat -anp|grep :8080`

Comment: IMO, there should be no problem. If you not using the 8080 port in other processes. (definitely)

Comment: My curiosity is that I have already set the port to 8082, but I do not know why I should check to see if the 8080 port is in use. Also, I wonder why there is no problem if the 8080 port is not in use. Is there any relationship between 8082 and 8080?

Comment: @1ambda
this is the result of CLI command in shell.
`$ sudo netstat -anp|grep :8080
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1931/java`